# Qt QGraphicsview how to hook to resize event

Tags: c++, qt

we're working on a Qt C++ Widget project and recently ve'we run into trouble. We're Qt rookies.

On our widget there are two `QGraphicsView` which need to resize automatically when the window is resized (we've done that) and keep the content inside them resized/fit/scaled accordingly to...

So we've figured we need to somehow hook to `onResizeEvent` or find which slot does it. But we're somehow lost as to how to do it.

P.S.: Please excuse my english.

Comment: IMO you are need to use [QBoxLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qboxlayout.html). And set this layout on [centralWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget). Do you use Qt Designer or everything is done by code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a QWidget you only need to reimplement the `resizeEvent` function.

```
void QWidget::resizeEvent ( QResizeEvent * event ) [virtual protected]
```

In the Qt documentation you can find the scribble example for a full code example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html

Alternatively you can install an event handler and grab the `QEvent::Resize`.
How to install event filters is described here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html

Answer (score 2):

You can make your custom class which inherits from QGraphicsView.  You should reimplement resizeEvent( QResizeEvent *event ) in your custom QGraphicsView like:

```
void MyView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{

    fitInView(0, 0, 500, 500,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

This way the view will always display the whole scene. I.e. if the window size is changed and the graphicsView is resized, The scene gets scaled and you can see everything appropriately.

Comment: Note for random bypassers: `fitInView()` inside `resizeEvent()`can be highly dangerous, causing infinite resize loop! So if you must do it, do safeguard against the loop.

Comment: @Smar What do you recommend as "safeguard"? I had the problem of streams of resizeEvents on Scrollbars getting shown/not shown. My solution: Explicit management of Scrollbar visibility in the paintEvent together with activation hysteresis in the routine that decides over visibility. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: @JürgenBöhm It’s been ages since I’ve touched this code, but generally something like a flag in an object that is used inside `resizeEvent()` to detect whether we already were here once. But exact solution would of course be context dependent.

Comment: @Smar Thank you for taking the time to write an answer. I first tried such a solution too (with a recursion_count integer in resizeEvent) but it did not help, because in the critical case there is a constant alternation between bigger and smaller vertical (or horizontal) size.

Answer (score 0):

If you are resizing in some slot then you can use `sender()`.
Btw you can always use debugger or logs/backtraces to get such information.